# how to check the record occurrence in mysql

Tags: mysql

kindly suggest me a sql query to sort this.
there is a non normalized table named test.there ar2 two fields on is primary key and it is auto incremented. other field 'name' and it is repetitive as follow.

[image]

so i just need to know what insert/update mysql query should i used to get below output in the 'occurrence' field.

[image]

eg:- in the 5th row name 'occurance' value is 3 because 'name'= "chanaka" has included 3 times totally in the table with including record 5.

Comment: Please consult any sql tutorial before asking such simple questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on mysql row number simulation

Here's an example

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,company_id
    -> , if(company_id <> @p ,@rn:=1, @rn:=@rn+1) occurance
    -> , @p:=company_id
    -> from medication, (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) rn
    -> order by company_id, id;
+------+------------+-----------+----------------+
| id   | company_id | occurance | @p:=company_id |
+------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|    1 |          1 |         1 |              1 |
|    2 |          1 |         2 |              1 |
|    3 |          1 |         3 |              1 |
|    4 |          2 |         1 |              2 |
|    5 |          2 |         2 |              2 |
|    6 |          2 |         3 |              2 |
|    8 |          2 |         4 |              2 |
|    7 |          3 |         1 |              3 |
+------+------------+-----------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to count "name" and that should get you the amount of 
 occurrences.

```
SELECT id, name, count(name) 
      FROM test 
     GROUP by name
```

Comment: select query is possible, but there should be a insert/update  query to fill the 'occurrence' field.

Comment: stackoverflow is no code writing service. You can easily convert this query to an update statement.